# How to add a line in every file in a directory with perl commandline

Tags: perl

I want to add a line at the beginning of every file in a directory.

```
perl -i.bkp -p -e 'print "#include top_level.reset\n" if $. == 1' *.reset
```

But this command is updating only the first file in the directory. I think this is because `$.` is not resetting for next file.

How to modify all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -1 *.reset | xargs -n 1 perl -i.bkp -p -e 'print "#include top_level.reset\n" if $. == 1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, $. is not reset between files when processing @ARGV. See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). You can work around it by explicitly closing ARGV on EOF - see [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html). But I would not bother, instead I would use the shell to iterate the files:

```
for f in *.reset; do perl -i.bkp -p -e 'print "#include top_level.reset\n" if $. == 1' $f; done
```